# Pythonic way of using type as function argument

Tags: python, function, types

What would be the most pythonic way to pass an object type as an agrgument in a function?

Let me give you an example. Let's say I was trying to get a configuration from an environment variable. Because all environment variables are strings I need to cast the value to the correct type.

To do this I need to tell the function the desired type. This is the purpose of the `coerce` argument. My first instinct is to pass in the desired type as the value for `coerce`. However, I am not sure if there are any implications or problems in doings so.

```py
import os

# The Function
def get_config(config: str, coerce: type, default: any, delimiter: str = ","):
    value = os.getenv(config, None)  # Get config from environment
    if value is None:
        return default  # Return default if config is None

    if coerce is bool:
        value = str2bool(value)  # Cast config to bool
    elif coerce is int:
        value = str2int(value)  # Cast config to int
    elif coerce is list:
        value = value.split(delimiter)  # Split string into list on delimiter

    return value  # Return the config value

# Usage
os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = "True"

test_var = get_config("TEST_VAR", bool, False)

print(test_var)  #  output is True
print(type(test_var))  # output is <class 'bool'>
```

To me this seems more clear and pythonic than using a string such as `"str"` or `"bool"` to specify the type. However, I would like to know if there could be any problems caused by passing around built in types as function arguments.

Comment: this is fine. do you have any specific concerns? This is probably a better fit for CodeReview not StackOverflow

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga No specific concern. Just not sure if this will come back to bite me later. Thank you for pointing out CodeReview I did not know it existed!

Answer (score 2):

Since all you are doing with the `type` argument is to compare it one by one to certain specific types that you're expecting, rather than actually using `type` to construct objects of that type, it is doing nothing different from passing in a string such as `'str'` or `'bool'` as an argument and compare it to several string constants.

Instead, you can make the conversion functions such as `str2bool` and `str2int` themselves an argument, so that you can call `coerce(value)` to convert `value` in a generic way. Store such conversion functions as attributes of a dedicated class for better readability, as demonstrated below:

```
import os
import typing

class to_type:
    bool = 'True'.__eq__
    int = int
    list = lambda s: s.split(',')

def get_config(config: str, coerce: typing.Callable = lambda s: s, default: any = None):
    value = os.getenv(config, None)
    if value is None:
        return default
    return coerce(value)

os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = "True"
print(get_config("TEST_VAR", to_type.bool))
os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = "2"
print(get_config("TEST_VAR", to_type.int))
os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = "a,b,c"
print(get_config("TEST_VAR", to_type.list))
os.environ["TEST_VAR"] = "foobar"
print(get_config("TEST_VAR"))
```

This outputs:

```
True
2
['a', 'b', 'c']
foobar
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the code and make it more powerful by just directly passing the conversion function (type annotations are left as an exercise):

```
def get_config(config, convert, default):
    value = os.getenv(config, None)
    return default if value is None else convert(value)

test_var = get_config("TEST_VAR", str2bool, False)
```

and perhaps having a helper function for the list case:

```
def make_str2list(delimiter=','):
    return lambda s: s.split(delimiter)

test_var = get_config("TEST_VAR", make_str2list(':'), [])
```

Comment: yup.  plus, you’re already getting some builtins like `str`, `int`.  casting strings via `str` does nothing, but it generalizes the concept

Answer (score 1):

In this specific instance, I'd argue that coerce should not be a **type**, but rather an **Enum**: both because `get_config` only supports a small set of possible values, and because it doesn't use the type values directly in its handling. If nothing else, the function signature is more precise with an Enum.

```
ConfigType = Enum('ConfigType', 'STR BOOL INT LIST')

def get_config(config: str, coerce: ConfigType, default: any, delimiter: str = ","):
    value = os.getenv(config, None)  # Get config from environment
    if value is None:
        return default  # Return default if config is None

    if coerce is ConfigType.BOOL:
        value = str2bool(value)  # Cast config to bool
    elif coerce is ConfigType.INT:
        value = str2int(value)  # Cast config to int
    elif coerce is ConfigType.LIST:
        value = value.split(delimiter)  # Split string into list on delimiter

    return value  # Return the config value
```

That said, if you really wanted to use **type** then Python 3.8 (which should be released in two days' time) supports [literal types](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/), meaning you could declare the function as follows:

```
def get_config(config: str, coerce: Literal[str, bool, int, list], default: any, delimiter: str = ","):
```